# How many real numbers satisfy the following

Tags: calculus

How many real numbers satisfy:
$$\sin x=\frac{x}{100}$$

I don't know where to start it how to do this at all. Can someone please help me?

Comment: try things like $\sin x = \frac{x}{3}$ first, where you can draw the graphs of $y = \sin x$ and $y =  \frac{x}{3}$ yourself. graph paper, five lines per inch: http://www.printablepaper.net/preview/grid-portrait-letter-5-index Valuable skill, drawing graphs

Comment: $5 \pi/2 \approx 7.85,$ so doing $\sin x = \frac{x}{8}$ for $-8 \leq x \leq 8$ should give a good idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

The following graph shows the $\sin{x}$ curve and $\frac {x}{100}$ straight line:
[image]

**Solution:**

The RHS takes on the values $-1 \le \sin{x} \le 1$.

The LHS is within these values when $-1 \le \frac {x}{100} \le 1\quad \Rightarrow -100 \le x \le 100$.

Within this range of $x$, we note that $\frac {x}{100} $ straight line cuts the $\sin {x}$ curve at $2$ points (roots) in the positive half-cycle of the sine curve when $x>0$ or negative half cycle when $x<0$.

Within $ -100 \le x \le 0$ and $0 \le x \le 100$, each has $\frac {100}{2\pi} \approx 15.9$ full cycles and $16$ positive or negative cycles.

Therefore the $\frac {x}{100} $ straight line cuts through $16\times 2 -1 = 31$ negative points and $31$ positive points and share $1$ point when $x=0$.
Therefore the number of points cut and hence the number or real roots is $31+31+1 = 63$.